# id card in datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to create a typ of board to show who's who in form of a datagrid. in each cell I have to show picture, name and department. any suggestion on how to do this ? something where I can create a template and inserted in datagridview control. thanks

Comment: Use `ListView` with `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add GridView control on page, bind with DataSet, display result.

Use two column in GridView,

1. BoundColumn for ID column
2. TemplateColumn for Picture Column, Name column, Department column

Also add OnRowDataBound event.

Write a sql query or stored procedure which return Desired reult from Database and create DataSet using it. Below is the sample code (not tested)

**IN .aspx page**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdImage" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        OnRowDataBound="gdImage_RowDataBound">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Information">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="ctrlImage" Width="15px" runat="server" alt='<%# 
             DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>'></asp:Image>
          <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
          <asp:Label ID="lblDept" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Dept") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**In Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SqlConnection con;
      SqlDataAdapter da;
      DataSet ds;
      SqlCommand cmd;        

     con = new       
          SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString);
     con.Open();

     da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id,Name,Dept,Image from tablename",con);
     ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
     gdImage.DataSource = ds;
     gdImage.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this, like I said, all the info(picture,name & dept) should be in same cell, not 3 different columns.

Comment: Fine, then use only template column, and done, see modified answer